# sudo nautilus warning

Tags: nautilus, gtk

Ubuntu 14.04 with current updates. This is what I get when I type this command "sudo nautilus"

(nautilus:3803): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

thank you

Comment: The messages are not unusual, but....
***NEVER*** run GUI applications with `sudo`. Use `gksu nautilus` (preferably) or `sudo -H nautilus`. See the excellent answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application

Comment: Excellent explanation of WHY. Now I understand. So i gather since I did not write and files using sudo and nautilus I most likely didn't screw anything up.

Comment: @JacobVlijm But am getting same warning and i am not running nautilus as root or sudo user.